# Angular 7 Table with Pagination, Sort, and Filter

Tags: angular, filter, datatable, pagination, tablesorter

Hi does anyone knows how to make a table with pagination, sort and filter in angular. I'm using Creative Tim's Argon Dashboard for Angular and I'm confused how I am going to integrate it to my project

Here's the documentation of the template [click me](https://demos.creative-tim.com/argon-dashboard-angular/documentation/contents)

Here's a sample code of the table

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table align-items-center table-flush">
      <thead class="thead-light">
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Project</th>
          <th scope="col">Budget</th>
          <th scope="col">Status</th>
          <th scope="col">Users</th>
          <th scope="col">Completion</th>
          <th scope="col"></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">
            <div class="media align-items-center">
              <a href="#" class="avatar rounded-circle mr-3">
                <img alt="Image placeholder" src="assets/img/theme/bootstrap.jpg">
              </a>
              <div class="media-body">
                <span class="mb-0 text-sm">Argon Design System</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </th>
          <td>
            $2,500 USD
          </td>
          <td>
            <span class="badge badge-dot mr-4">
              <i class="bg-warning"></i> pending
            </span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="avatar-group">
              <a href="#" class="avatar avatar-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Ryan Tompson">
                <img alt="Image placeholder" src="assets/img/theme/team-1-800x800.jpg" class="rounded-circle">
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="avatar avatar-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Romina Hadid">
                <img alt="Image placeholder" src="assets/img/theme/team-2-800x800.jpg" class="rounded-circle">
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="avatar avatar-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Alexander Smith">
                <img alt="Image placeholder" src="assets/img/theme/team-3-800x800.jpg" class="rounded-circle">
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="avatar avatar-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Jessica Doe">
                <img alt="Image placeholder" src="assets/img/theme/team-4-800x800.jpg" class="rounded-circle">
              </a>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
              <span class="mr-2">60%</span>
              <div>
                <div class="progress">
                  <div class="progress-bar bg-warning" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 60%;"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td class="text-right">
            <div ngbDropdown placement="bottom-right">
              <a class="btn btn-sm btn-icon-only text-light"  ngbDropdownToggle>
                <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
              </a>
              <div ngbDropdownMenu class=" dropdown-menu-right dropdown-menu-arrow">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">
            <div class="media align-items-center">
              <a href="#" class="avatar rounded-circle mr-3">
                <img alt="Image placeholder" src="assets/img/theme/angular.jpg">
              </a>
              <div class="media-body">
                <span class="mb-0 text-sm">Angular Now UI Kit PRO</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </th>
          <td>
            $1,800 USD
          </td>
          <td>
            <span class="badge badge-dot">
              <i class="bg-success"></i> completed
            </span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="avatar-group">
              <a href="#" class="avatar avatar-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Ryan Tompson">
                <img alt="Image placeholder" src="assets/img/theme/team-1-800x800.jpg" class="rounded-circle">
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="avatar avatar-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Romina Hadid">
                <img alt="Image placeholder" src="assets/img/theme/team-2-800x800.jpg" class="rounded-circle">
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="avatar avatar-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Alexander Smith">
                <img alt="Image placeholder" src="assets/img/theme/team-3-800x800.jpg" class="rounded-circle">
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="avatar avatar-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Jessica Doe">
                <img alt="Image placeholder" src="assets/img/theme/team-4-800x800.jpg" class="rounded-circle">
              </a>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
              <span class="mr-2">100%</span>
              <div>
                <div class="progress">
                  <div class="progress-bar bg-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 100%;"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td class="text-right">
            <div ngbDropdown  placement="bottom-right">
              <a class="btn btn-sm btn-icon-only text-light"  ngbDropdownToggle>
                <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
              </a>
              <div ngbDropdownMenu class=" dropdown-menu-right dropdown-menu-arrow">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">
            <div class="media align-items-center">
              <a href="#" class="avatar rounded-circle mr-3">
                <img alt="Image placeholder" src="assets/img/theme/sketch.jpg">
              </a>
              <div class="media-body">
                <span class="mb-0 text-sm">Black Dashboard</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </th>
          <td>
            $3,150 USD
          </td>
          <td>
            <span class="badge badge-dot mr-4">
              <i class="bg-danger"></i> delayed
            </span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="avatar-group">
              <a href="#" class="avatar avatar-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Ryan Tompson">
                <img alt="Image placeholder" src="assets/img/theme/team-1-800x800.jpg" class="rounded-circle">
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="avatar avatar-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Romina Hadid">
                <img alt="Image placeholder" src="assets/img/theme/team-2-800x800.jpg" class="rounded-circle">
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="avatar avatar-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Alexander Smith">
                <img alt="Image placeholder" src="assets/img/theme/team-3-800x800.jpg" class="rounded-circle">
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="avatar avatar-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Jessica Doe">
                <img alt="Image placeholder" src="assets/img/theme/team-4-800x800.jpg" class="rounded-circle">
              </a>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
              <span class="mr-2">72%</span>
              <div>
                <div class="progress">
                  <div class="progress-bar bg-danger" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="72" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 72%;"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td class="text-right">
            <div ngbDropdown  placement="top-right">
              <a class="btn btn-sm btn-icon-only text-light"  ngbDropdownToggle>
                <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
              </a>
              <div ngbDropdownMenu class=" dropdown-menu-right dropdown-menu-arrow">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">
            <div class="media align-items-center">
              <a href="#" class="avatar rounded-circle mr-3">
                <img alt="Image placeholder" src="assets/img/theme/react.jpg">
              </a>
              <div class="media-body">
                <span class="mb-0 text-sm">React Material Dashboard</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </th>
          <td>
            $4,400 USD
          </td>
          <td>
            <span class="badge badge-dot">
              <i class="bg-info"></i> on schedule
            </span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="avatar-group">
              <a href="#" class="avatar avatar-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Ryan Tompson">
                <img alt="Image placeholder" src="assets/img/theme/team-1-800x800.jpg" class="rounded-circle">
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="avatar avatar-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Romina Hadid">
                <img alt="Image placeholder" src="assets/img/theme/team-2-800x800.jpg" class="rounded-circle">
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="avatar avatar-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Alexander Smith">
                <img alt="Image placeholder" src="assets/img/theme/team-3-800x800.jpg" class="rounded-circle">
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="avatar avatar-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Jessica Doe">
                <img alt="Image placeholder" src="assets/img/theme/team-4-800x800.jpg" class="rounded-circle">
              </a>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
              <span class="mr-2">90%</span>
              <div>
                <div class="progress">
                  <div class="progress-bar bg-info" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="90" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 90%;"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td class="text-right">
            <div ngbDropdown   placement="top-right">
              <a class="btn btn-sm btn-icon-only text-light"  ngbDropdownToggle>
                <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
              </a>
              <div ngbDropdownMenu class=" dropdown-menu-right dropdown-menu-arrow">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">
            <div class="media align-items-center">
              <a href="#" class="avatar rounded-circle mr-3">
                <img alt="Image placeholder" src="assets/img/theme/vue.jpg">
              </a>
              <div class="media-body">
                <span class="mb-0 text-sm">Vue Paper UI Kit PRO</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </th>
          <td>
            $2,200 USD
          </td>
          <td>
            <span class="badge badge-dot mr-4">
              <i class="bg-success"></i> completed
            </span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="avatar-group">
              <a href="#" class="avatar avatar-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Ryan Tompson">
                <img alt="Image placeholder" src="assets/img/theme/team-1-800x800.jpg" class="rounded-circle">
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="avatar avatar-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Romina Hadid">
                <img alt="Image placeholder" src="assets/img/theme/team-2-800x800.jpg" class="rounded-circle">
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="avatar avatar-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Alexander Smith">
                <img alt="Image placeholder" src="assets/img/theme/team-3-800x800.jpg" class="rounded-circle">
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="avatar avatar-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Jessica Doe">
                <img alt="Image placeholder" src="assets/img/theme/team-4-800x800.jpg" class="rounded-circle">
              </a>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
              <span class="mr-2">100%</span>
              <div>
                <div class="progress">
                  <div class="progress-bar bg-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 100%;"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td class="text-right">
            <div ngbDropdown   placement="top-right">
              <a class="btn btn-sm btn-icon-only text-light"  ngbDropdownToggle>
                <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
              </a>
              <div ngbDropdownMenu class=" dropdown-menu-right dropdown-menu-arrow">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Here's a sample code of the pagination used

```
<nav aria-label="...">
<ul class="pagination pagination-sm">
  <li class="page-item disabled">
    <a class="page-link" href="#" tabindex="-1">1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">2</a></li>
  <li class="page-item active"><a class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
</ul>
```

I don't know about the filter. I really don't know how to start I'm kinda new to this. I came from AngularJS 1.6.x

edit: I would like to know I can still use the table design from the template if I integrated some of your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Angular-Datatable](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/basic/zero-config). It is very simple to integrate.

HTML:

```
<table datatable >
</table
```

app.module:

`import { DataTablesModule } from 'angular-datatables';`

```
  imports: [
    DataTablesModule
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have limitations on what to use, I would advise you to maybe take a look at angular material, especially the table component which integrates filtering, pagination, ...

https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview

overall very simple to use

Comment: can I still use the ui from the template if I used that?

Comment: you can still override css of material table, we do it for our project and it works fine, I mostly use it for easy implementation then adapt the styling of it

Comment: its working but looked like crap. how do I overwrite it?

Answer (score 0):

Another nice free library with data table and more is [PrimeNG](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table).

It's easy to integrate and have many controls. Basic styling is free, full-fledged designs are paid if you want them.

Comment: Seems easy to understand I would look into this thanks! tho I still like to use the ui of the table that came with the template

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ag-grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/) which is rich-featured grid, could be use simply to show data with basic functions like sort, filter and pagination but also can be used to do complex operations e.g. export, grouped data if needed (paid version). Comes with pre-defined styling themes dark, light and more.

Comment: wow that's a powerful tool but unfortunately I'm just gonna use the table with those function mentioned above

Comment: that's up to you. but I recommended because it is really quick and easy to implement if you want to use just basic functions. Consider specially styling which is painful if you need to change.